# how to remove index.php from opencart v 3.0.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, opencart

I have installed `opencart` version `3.0.2` in my localhost. everything works fine except seo friendly url. when i try to remove `index.php?route=...`
then i got `404` error. when i tried following code in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

then `404` error gone but products doesn't display.
when i getback default `.htaccess` file then seo friendly url shows `404` error.
please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn seo urls on from your admin panel.
Go to System>Settings>Edit>Server> check yes for use seo urls.
and be sure that all your products and categories have the right seo-url data and replace any space by '-'.

Comment: add this into your .htaccess
RewriteBase /Yourstore/
be sure that yourstore in the root of your server,

Comment: Thanks i forgot to include store name in RewriteBase